# Reading a file line by line in C, concat doesn't work after realloc

Tags: c

Like in the topic, I try to read a file line by line, but the program is not doing what I want. So what i tried is to check, if there is an \n at the end, and if not the space for the line is not enough, so I reallocate it, and put the position of the line -> to the old length, in order to concatenate the next what will be read:

```
    int max_line_len = 10000;
    int line_pos = 0;
    char *line;
    line = malloc(sizeof(char)*max_line_len);

    while (fgets(&line[line_pos], max_line_len, file) != NULL) {

        int line_length = strlen(line);
        if (line[line_length - 1] == '\n') {

            // do something to the lines
            line_pos = 0; 
        } else {
            max_line_len *= 2;
            line_pos = line_length;
            line = realloc(sizeof(char) * max_line_len);
        }
    }
}
fclose(file);
free(line);
```

But after the realloc a whole line isn't even read, and he keeps entering the (else part

Comment: Is this your full code...?

Comment: This is not the real code. That `realloc` call should not even compile.

Comment: no its not, but the only thing I thought it would be important, since the error occurs in the realloc part

Comment: Yes, sorry, kit is :
line = realloc(line, sizeof(char)*max_line_len);

Comment: I reformatted your code snippet and it shows, that the `free(line)` is using a different 'line' than the one shown here, because the first one is out of scope.

Comment: Oh ok, so what does it exactly mean :S.. I mean my debug error is exactly that: incorent checksum for freed object, object was probably modified after being freed..

Comment: So what is line?! Where is line?!

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads too much. After first `realloc` `line_pos` is 9999 and `max_line_len` is 20000, which means you end up reading to indexes 9999 .. 29999, when the last valid index of `line` is only 19999.

Comment: Ok I know that now, but can't you give some hint how to fix it?

Comment: @malajedala You need to keep track of how much free space your buffer has. Simple substraction might do: `max_line_len - line_pos`.

Comment: But I thought this is managed by the realloc :S..it gets more space for the read :S??

Comment: @malajedala It *is* managed by the `realloc`. But `fgets` only knows what you tell it.

Comment: So you propose to check if the max_line_len - line_pos is higher than the length of the new read part? Or of the whole line

Comment: Sorry i was being to fast, I read again the fgets description, i think this should do it
       while (fgets(&line[line_pos], max_line_len - line_pos, file) != NULL)

Comment: @malajedala Yes, that's what I meant.